# How to disable module for a particular plugin in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I have to disable plugin for a particular module. Is this possible in Joomla? I have light box plugin which I need to disable for this particular module which is loaded in article pages.

Comment: Try adding some specific details like version, what all you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a content plugin, you can disable PREPARE CONTENT on the OPTIONS tab of that particular module.

[image]